# Como faço para criar essa navbar?

Tags: html, css, nav-bar

Quero deixar meu nav-bar igual a [essa](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/menu-png-a8029ad2-e316-40e4-8307-232533848c59).

Eu quero deixar, uma divisão no meio do nav-bar, não faço a minima ideia de como fazer isso.

Meu código agora:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="navbar-fixed-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
 </head>
  <body>  
} 
  <div class="sticky-top">
  <style>
      <style>
  </style>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-white my-0 py-0">      
      <img class="img-responsive" src="logocerto.png">
       <style>
      .img-responsive{
                  margin-left:400px;                 
                  height:300px;
                 } 
     </style>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <style>
   .jumbotron-fluid {
background-image: url(pao.jpg);
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;}
  </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light mb-3">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    BOOKS
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Branding Sutra</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

    </div>
</div>
  <style>
   body {
 background-image: url(pao.jpg);
 color: white;
 widht:200px;
 height:200px;
  </style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

 </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dei uma ajeitada no seu código que tinha muitos erros, como 2 bodys, divs que não fecham nada, tens que ficar atento a isso pois faz toda a diferença, os  de CSS que você abriu tem que  ficar dentro do Head.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="navbar-fixed-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            .img-responsive{
                margin-left:400px;
                height:300px;
            }
            .jumbotron-fluid {
                background-image: url(pao.jpg);
                background-size: cover;
                height: 100%;}
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>  

      <div class="sticky-top">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-white my-0 py-0">      
          <img class="img-responsive" src="logocerto.png">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light mb-3">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        BOOKS
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Branding Sutra</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"> <!-- alterando esses números consegue aumentar e diminuir cada campo -->
                TESTE
                    </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                TESTE
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- ESSE É O ESPAÇO EM BRANCO -->
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                teste
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                TESTE
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alguém que diga ao rapaz que a navbar é feia que dói, não vai ser funcional e em mobile não vai ficar grande coisa xD

Comment: Obrigado mesmo! é que eu inventei de fazer um site assim para um trabalho da escola e agora tem que ser exatamente igual, obrigado mesmo :D